# Regex to capture a word before a constant in a sentence

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have multiple statements that end with a constant and have a variable (file name) in front of that constant.

Examples :

- **Conversion routine for the NYC.GENX application.** - should show **'NYC.GENX'**
- **Conversion routine for the CAP-GENY application.** - should show **'CAP-GENY'**
- **Conversion routine for the NNUAT_CHECK application.** - should show **'NNUAT_CHECK'**
- **Created on 1/1/14 11:40 AM for RUN_SCRIPT application.** - should show **'NNUAT_CHECK'**
- **Event created on 2/2/14 12:29 PM for the STOP_SERVER application.** - should show **'STOP_SERVER'**

As you can see above, every sentence ends with a constant **'application.'**. I want to capture the word before that constant in each of the statements.

Is there a simple regex that can do this ? I want to avoid multiple lines of code in java involving strings to do this.

I have tried this but it fetches all the individual words in a statement while I want just the one word before a constant.

```
\w+(?=.*:)
```

Comment: Great, that works but could you explain what each expression does please ? I know \S+ matches 1 or more non-white space chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - can you please post this as an answer instead of a comment - I can accept it since it looks very simple and efficient.

Comment: I posted and remove the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your expected matches consist of non-whitespace chars, thus, you may use

```
\S+(?=\s+application)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nHeDz/1).

Here,

- `\S+` - matches 1 or more chars other than whitespace...
- `(?=\s+application)` - *only* if immediately followed with 1+ whitespace chars (`\s+`) and an `application` substring.

Another solution might be to match 1+ uppercase letters followed with any punctuation and then again 1+ uppercase letters (that is, if the requirement looks like this). Then use

```
[A-Z]+(?:\p{Punct}[A-Z]+)*(?=\s+application)
```

See [another (PCRE variation with `[[:punct:]]`, in Java it is `\p{Punct}`) demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nHeDz/2).

Comment: Thank you ! very elegant solution !

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `"\\b([A-Z_\\-\\.]+)\\s+application"`

`\\b` - word boundaries

`A-Z_\\-\\.` - matched word can contain only letters from A to Z, underscores, dashes and dots

`s+` - one or more whitespace characters

As you see, matched word is contained in capture group inside parenthesis.

Comment: thank you for your answer but when I tried, it didnt seem to work ! The other solution seemed very concise and elegant and hence went with that. Appreciate your help though. Thank you again !

Comment: @Prashanth I'll try to improve my answer as I now have access to online compiler, hope you even look at it a bit later :-)

Comment: sure, will do. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The (\S+) captures all non-space in a group followed by \s+ white space character(s) and the word application.

```
\b(\S+)\s+application
```

this will put the desired text in a capture group.

Or combined with Wiktor's.

```
\b(\S+)(?=\s+application)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZAENJ/2)